# I getting a web page content with javascript code Curl

Tags: php, curl

I getting a web page content with Curl. But I can't getting Javascript variables (file,preview) in other page. Code is that;

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

var config = {
 controller: 'file',
 player: 'videojs',
 autoplay: false,
 collection: true,
 language: 'en',
 ip_hash: '86e8a342dd519037c88595bca8471aaa'
};

var params = {
 file: {"mp4_720":"http:\/\/video.com\/file\/Z.mp4","mp4_1080":"http:\/\/video.com\/file\/Z.mp4"},
 preview: 'https://video.com/file/Z.jpg'
};

</script>
```

I have get "file" and "preview" params. But I didn't..

Answer (score 0):

You can likely manipulate the string to get that information; however if that doesn't work for you - you can use [Facebook PHP WebDriver](https://facebook.github.io/php-webdriver/classes/JavaScriptExecutor.html#method_executeScript) to run that JavaScript in PHP, a crude example would be:

```
$driver = RemoteWebDriver::create($host, DesiredCapabilities::chrome());
$file = $this->webdriver->executeScript("return params[file]", array());
$preview = $this->webdriver->executeScript("return params[preview]", array());
```

There is [an example of using php-webdriver](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver/blob/community/example.php) on Github.

Comment: I saw it very complicated. How can a simpler structure be built?